# Turning SLI on & off using command line

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, script, sli

I've got three monitors here, using two graphic cards ( in my case 2 * Gigabyte GTX 460 ) and I want to run these in SLI-mode when I play games and in other cases I want all three monitors setup in a certain way.

I've used the `DisplaySwitch.exe` in System32 ( Windows 7 ) do trigger Cloneing but I don't know how to take this to the next level. I've also used `QRes` ( some OSS ) to change resolution.

For instance the following has been used to refresh my displays to go into cloning mode:

```
C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /internal
Y:\Software\QRes.exe /x:1920 /y:1080
C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /clone
```

And this is the setup that I want to acheive when I am in "cloning + extended"-mode:

[image]

And when I am in SLI-mode I want to display the image on monitor 1 and extend monitor 3 and switch on SLI.

Any suggestions on how I can do this? I could live with turning SLI on and off manually, but doing the "extend"/"clone" bits is just a hassle, I don't know if DisplaySwitch will let me control that as much as I'd like.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find any command line programs to do this you could potentially work up a pair of AutoHotkey scripts that set up your system the way you were wanting it.

Granted it's nowhere near as clean as having dedicated programs to do it, but it would save you a lot of mouse-clicks.

Check out [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)